# How to handle DOM events using Haskell with webkitgtk(3)

Tags: haskell, dom, webkit

Is it possible in principle to handle DOM events (that normally are handled with Javascript) in Haskell using the webkitgtk3? I see examples how to handle Gtk events (using `on`), but DOM events have different type signatures, and don't work with `on`.

I see there is a function addEventListener

[addEventListener](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/webkitgtk3-0.14.1.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-WebKit-DOM-EventTarget.html#v:addEventListener)

but I cannot find any examples of its use to call a handler written in Haskell. Ideally it would be to make webkit to translate a DOM event into Gtk event.

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here is what I found out myself, maybe this example also helps somebody else.

https://gist.github.com/dmgolubovsky/72803f4f9f179bd5b93b